# Property of pole at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis

My textbook states: If $f$ has at most a pole at $z=\infty$, then it is analytic everywhere outside a sufficiently large circle.

$f$ is a single valued function that has no singularities other than poles in the finite part of the plane and at $z=\infty$. Although there is no analyticity assumption in this statement, it is assumed throughout the textbook.

Can someone explain to me why this is true?

Comment: And $f$ is? Meromorphic? What is yor definition of pole?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to elaborate. This is part of a proof to show that $f$ is a rational function.

Comment: Definition of pole at $\infty$ is that $f$ has a pole at $\infty$ if $\phi(z)=f(\frac{1}{z})$ has a pole at $z=0$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Definition of pole at $\infty$ is that $f$ has a pole at $\infty$ if $\phi(z)=f(\frac{1}{z})$ has a pole at $z=0$.

Which brings us to the question: what is the definition of a pole at $z=0$? It is an ***isolated** singularity* of certain kind (one for which there is $n>0$ such that $z^n \phi(z)$ has a finite, nonzero limit as $z\to 0$). The word *isolated* requires $\phi$ to have no other singularities in some neighborhood of $0$. That is, there is $r>0$ such that $f$ is analytic in $\{z: 0<|z|<r\}$.

Going back to $f$, we see that $f$ is analytic in $\{z: 1/r<|z|<\infty\}$.  Which is exactly what *analytic everywhere outside a sufficiently large circle* was meant to say.